# how to create animated transition screen in xcode

Tags: ios, animation

I'm just a new man to IOS. Here is the storyboard of my app:

[image: storyboard of my app]

I made an animated file *gif and I want to add it between `ViewController 1` and `ViewController 2`. This is how it goes: 
when I hit on the button on `VC1`, animated screen will be showed up (**like a loading screen**), and the view 2 will be showed up afterward.

How can I do it?

Comment: you could also have a look at the new repo which facebook released a few hours ago. It is an "extensible animation engine for iOS" (https://github.com/facebook/pop)

Answer (score 0):

use this this seems close to your problem

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:2];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];      ECAddToFavoriteViewController *addTofav = [[ECAddToFavoriteViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ECAddToFavoriteViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:addTofav animated:YES];
    [[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

Comment: So I use your code in (void)viewDidLoad of viewcontroller2.m? and I need to change your class ECAddToFavoriteViewController with my own VC2? How about @"ECAddToFavoriteViewController" and @"SwitchToView1" ?

Comment: ECAddToFavoriteViewController is my own class name you can use your and  SwitchToView1 is only key you can use yours